# how to change password on my Azure Windows 2012 R2 admin account

Tags: windows, passwords, windows-server-2012-r2, azure

I log on to my Azure Windows 2012 R2 VM with Remote Desktop...

THIS DIDN'T WORK:  control panel > admin tools > Comp Mgmt > Users > my account > right-click > All Tasks > Set password:
I get a scary warning that says I might lose data, and to instead use CTRL-ALT-DELETE and change password.

THIS DIDN'T WORK:   CTRL-ALT-END  (its popup menu had no 'change password')

Comment: "I get a scary warning that says I might lose data" - This only applies if you use EFS.  It sounds like you have a group policy setting, that is preventing you from changing your password before it needs to be changed. You can configure a policy that prevents passwords from being change repeatedly (which is set by default is enforced to a default value).  If you have recently changed the password that is like the case, so if that is the case, resetting the password is your only choice.

Comment: I have not changed password since last year.

Comment: I would check what the applicable group policy is set to, which I don't know the name of, I just know it exists.  Otherwise just reset the password, you can also prevent an account from changing it's password, so make sure that isn't set also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the password via the Azure portal.

Select your virtual machine then click Support + Troubleshooting > Reset password. The password reset blade is displayed:

[image]

Enter the username and a new password, then click Update. Try connecting to your VM again.

Ref: [How to reset the Remote Desktop service or its login password in a Windows VM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/reset-rdp)